# Placed all stone what shall I do now?

Tags: candy-box-2

I have all four stone and in place I have tried to press and click on them but it won't work what do I do?

Answer (score 2):

Now you can actually open the Candy Box.  If you haven't got it yet, you're not quite done...

> The Lonely House is located north of the Village, and has the Candy Box.  Just mouse around the forest above the village until you find a place you can click.

If you already have the Box and just don't know where to find it, it's in your "The Candy Box" section of the top bar.

Exact instructions, just in case:

> Place all four stone.  The Talking Candy appears on the altar above the four stones.  Pick it up.  Click the Candy Box at the top of the screen.  The Talking Candy will now appear underneath your Candy Box, and ask if you want him to open the box.  Click Yes.  Three new options will appear in your top bar, Inside Your Box, The Computer, and The Arena.  Click Inside Your Box to see the end credits, The Computer for the end of game "freeplay mode", and The Arena for post-game challenge modes.

Comment: but how do i open ittt

Comment: @noah Answer updated, will update again if I notice something during my playthrough.

Comment: @noah Answer updated again, it was fun playing through the game again!  Enjoy your candies!